# How do i fix "Error connecting to SQL Server: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433" when connecting node.js to SQL Server?

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm trying to make a connection to SQL Server from node.js, however I keep getting this same error.

I've tried different variations of the configuration, but it hasn't really worked.

This is my code - I've enabled TCP/IP, I've got both SQL Server and SQL Server browser running, I've tried every form by every YT video but the error won't go away.

```
const sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'Student',
    port: 1433,
    dialect: "mssql",
    dialectOptions: {
        instanceName: "MSSQLEXPRESS",
        validateBulkLoadParameters:false,
        encrypt: false,
    }
};
sql.connect(config, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(Error connecting to SQL Server: ${err});
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to SQL Server successfully!');
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you read the [mssql documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) yet? To connect to a named instance you'd use `server: 'yourServerNameOrIpAddressHere\\yourInstanceNameHere'`. `port:` isn't actually an option, if you want to connect to a non-default port you'd use `server: 'yourServerNameOrIpAddressHere,23456'`. If you know the port number specify that instead of an instance name as it avoids the sometimes-problematic instance name resolution process via the target machine's SQL Browser service.

Comment: Since it seems you could be using an instance of SQL Server Express edition - have you checked in SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager to confirm that its TCP/IP server protocol is enabled? Is it actually listening on port 1433? (That would be unusual for Express.)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes it is enabled, it was the first thing i did when i ran into the problem :(

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I've also checked the docs and tried to fix it based on them but it didn't work

Comment: Can you connect to the SQL server manually (i.e. not via node)? That would let you narrow down whether the issue is with the SQL server or on the node side.